# What is better array or linked list in searching?

Tags: algorithm

I read about the linked list and array and most of I read that is the array better in searching and linked list better in insertion and deletions but ther is no proof.
I need someone tell me why?!

Answer (score 1):

In an array you can quickly access an arbitrary element (say the 17th), the same operation in a linked list requires to access all elements before it as well.

On the other hand, to insert an element in the array means to move all elements coming after it one slot up to make room, in the linked list this operation is just a manipulation of a fixed number of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

**Insertion and deletion**

In array, Insertion and Deletion operation takes more time, as the memory locations are consecutive and fixed.

In case of linked list, a new element is stored at the first free and available memory location, with only a single overhead step of storing the address of memory location in the previous node of linked list. Insertion and Deletion operations are fast in linked list.

**Searching**

Array supports Random Access, which means elements can be accessed directly using their index, like arr[0] for 1st element, arr[6] for 7th element etc. Hence, accessing elements in an array is fast with a constant time complexity of O(1).

Linked List supports Sequential Access, which means to access any element/node in a linked list, we have to sequentially traverse the complete linked list, upto that element. To access nth element of a linked list, time complexity is O(n).

I copied theses point from https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/linked-list-vs-array . You can go to this link and get an idea about these two structure.